# How to calculate z transform of $x(n)=(n-1)(\frac{1}{2})^{n-2}u(n-2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, transformation

Let $x(n)=(n-1)(\frac{1}{2})^{n-2}u(n-2)$, where $u(n-2)$ is shifted unit step function. How can I calculate z transform of this function?

By definition, $X(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}x(n)z^{-n}=\sum_{n=2}^{n=\infty}(n-1)(\frac{1}{2})^{n-2}z^{-n}$.

How to calculate this sum? If there was no $(n-1)$, this would be geometric series and its sum can be easily calculated.

Comment: Is $|z| > 1/2$?

Comment: Yes,  |z| > 1 / 2

Comment: take the derivative of the geometric series in $z$ (taking its primitive solves in the same way the $\sum_n \frac{z^n}{n}$ case)

Answer (score 0):

We can write the sum as:

$$\frac1{z} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\left(\frac1{2z}\right)^{n - 1}$$

Now we use (for $|\xi| < 1$):

$$\frac1{(1-\xi)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\xi^{n-1}$$